# ehcache configuration in Spring framework

Tags: spring, ehcache, spring-4, spring-cache

I am trying to load some context from an RSS feed and pass it as a cache to the client using ehcache library in spring. here is my code :

```
    import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
@Service
public class GlossaryReaderService {

    @Cacheable(value = "glossaryList")
    public List<Glossary> readGlossary(String url) {

        XmlReader reader = null;
        List<Glossary> extractedGlossay = new ArrayList<Glossary>();
        SyndEntry entry;
        SyndContent desc;
        Glossary glossaryList = null;
        try {
            String decodedURL = URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
            reader = new XmlReader(new URL(decodedURL));
            SyndFeed feed = new SyndFeedInput().build(reader);

            for (Iterator i = feed.getEntries().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                entry = (SyndEntry) i.next();
                desc = entry.getDescription();
                if (desc != null) { ...
                        extractedGlossay.add(glossaryList);
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException | IllegalArgumentException | FeedException e) {
            log.error("Error reading RSS feed", e);
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(reader);
        }

        return extractedGlossay;
    }
```

also under at /webmi/src/main/resources/ehcache.xml I have the echahe.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <ehcache>
  <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="500" eternal="true"
    overflowToDisk="false" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />
  <cache name="info" maxElementsInMemory="500" eternal="true"
    overflowToDisk="false" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />
   </ehcache>
```

but the problem is that when I want to add the beans in the application-content it gives error. here is the partin application-content.xml :

```
<!--  CACHE CONFIGURATION  -->
<cache:annotation-driven />
<bean id="cacheManager"
class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager"
p:cache-manager-ref="ehcache" />
    <bean id="ehcache class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:config location="classpath:ehcache.xml" />
```

but it give me the following error:

```
 2014-02-26 16:56:47 [ERROR] ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager] for bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager] for bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1266)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:438)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:260)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1258)
    ... 31 more
Feb 26, 2014 4:56:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager] for bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I have been working on this the whole day, but I dont dont know what is the problem. please if anybody know the answer, help !!!

**Edit:**
I have added the spring-contect-support, here is the dependencies in the Pom :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Ehcache -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

but the error has been changed to the following :

```
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default-dispatcher] in context with path [/webmi] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find cache named [glossaryList] for CacheableOperation[public java.util.List com.service.GlossaryReaderService.readGlossary(java.lang.String)] caches=[glossaryList] | condition='' | key=''] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find cache named [glossaryList] for CacheableOperation[public java.util.List com.service.GlossaryReaderService.readGlossary(java.lang.String)] caches=[glossaryList] | condition='' | key=''
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.getCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:163)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CacheOperationContext.<init>(CacheAspectSupport.java:443)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.getOperationContext(CacheAspectSupport.java:173)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.createOperationContext(CacheAspectSupport.java:404)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:192)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at com.lloydsbanking.webmi.service.GlossaryReaderService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$26769e11.readGlossary(<generated>)
    at com.webmi.web.RssController.getGlossory(RssController.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Comment: Are you sure you have all dependencies fulfilled?

Comment: maybe show your pom file

Comment: @user261002 do you have `spring-context-x.x.x.jar` file in your project buildpath?

Comment: There is a syntax error on the bean declaration, missing `"` at the end of `id` attribute

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This class is located in the `spring-context-support` module that is optional. Please make sure that you have added it as a dependency of your project.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
   <version>X.Y.Z.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 10):

Your spring configuration is excellent, i see examples with lots of typos on the web.

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" p:cache-manager-ref="ehcache" />
<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:configLocation="/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml" />
```

Remark: you need both dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

first one is implementation second one is spring wrapper around it. If you don't use both you will have exceptions related to finding implementing class.

Comment: Thanks, The solutions worked for me. I used below configuration in my spring boot application. <dependency>
   <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
   <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
   <version>2.9.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> I even Added the dependency still I am facing this issue:
> ```
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
> org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
 <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
 <version>2.8.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>    
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>   
<artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>   
<version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32248006)

Answer (score -1):

Use below maven dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also, make sure that you use version 4.3.4. Don't use 5.0.6 and other latest version, It didn't work for me.